# How to prevent jquery global selector selects something outside of the Polymer element

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

I am trying to use a jquery based library within my Polymer element `<my-element>`. But once there are more than one of such `<my-element>` in one page, the library only selects first one because it is selecting an `id` that is unique within one instance of `<my-element>` but repeated in multiple ones. How to give jquery selector a domain so that it will only select within it?

Comment: I am using Polymer 1.0 and please answer based on not switching library nor argue about how I should not use jquery with Polymer

Comment: are you using ShadowDOM or ShadyDOM?

Comment: ShadyDOM @NicholasKyriakides

Comment: ShadowDOM shouldn't have this problem, at least theoretically

Comment: Okay, good to know. But I am using Polymer 1.0, migrating to 2.0 is not doable at the moment.

Comment: Polymer 1.0 has support for ShadowDOM as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because [jQuery's id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) is optimized to fetch just the first one:

> Each `id` value must be used only once within a document. If more than
>   one element has been assigned the same ID, queries that use that ID
>   will only select the first matched element in the DOM. This behavior
>   should not be relied on, however; a document with more than one
>   element using the same ID is invalid.

---

You can pass [jQuery selector's context](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) as its second parameter (interestingly, if you pass multiple contexts, it selectes multiples ids):

```js
// Initialize selected domains
$('#init-id', '.first-domain, .second-domain').initializeLibrary();

// Initialize all id in DOM
$('#init-id', '*').initializeLibrary();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="first-domain">
  <img id="init-id" />
</div>
<div class="second-domain">
  <img id="init-id" />
</div>
<div class="do-not-initialize-domain">
  <img id="init-id" />
</div>
```

---

Alternatively, your component could initialize itself with [`Polymer.dom(this.root)`](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding):

```
<dom-module id="my-component">

  <template>
    My component - yay!
  </template>

  <script>

    Polymer({

      is: 'my-component',

      ready: function() {
        $(Polymer.dom(this.root)).initializeLibrary();
      }

    });

  </script>

</dom-module>
```